# How to merge users in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, merge

I need to make something to merge some users in PGSQL but I think that pgsql don't own the MERGE property. I just want to know how to make two users to be matched like this :

```
id | name | username | mail
1  | toto | tata     | toto.tata@gmail.com
2  | titi | tutu     | titi.tutu@gmail.com
```

Here I want to chose which data I would like I want to say that I want to merge only username from 2 to 1 so the result would be :

```
id | name | username | mail
1  | toto | tutu     | toto.tata@gmail.com
```

Comment: How you are relating those two rows? They don't share any common column value.

Comment: That's the point, I need to just choose two line to merge and said which column I want to merge. I need to say which id I want to merge together.

Comment: What will be the merging condition? max() or min() or anything else?

Comment: The condition is : I pass two id like I said so like that : id1: 1, id2: 2 and after that I said which column I want to merge from 2 to 1. So it will just be specific ID that I give which will merge. the second merge into the first. And if you want to know what I want to merge it's to the users to choose which column he want to merge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to select all the columns for first id and the column you need with second id will be a subquery in select list. Please check below answer for selecting merged result.

Schema and insert statements:

```
 create table users (id int , name varchar(50), username varchar(50), mail varchar(50));
 insert into users values (1  , 'toto' , 'tata'     , 'toto.tata@gmail.com');
 insert into users values (2  , 'titi' , 'tutu'     , 'titi.tutu@gmail.com');
```

Query:

```
 select id,name,(select username from users where id=2) username,mail from users where id=1
```

Output:

| id | name | username | mail |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | toto | tutu | toto.tata@gmail.com |

*db<fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=05312ca24775add1048c5891013f347c)*

To merge the rows within the table you can first update first row with data from second row then delete the second row. Try this:

Schema and insert statements:

```
 create table users (id int , name varchar(50), username varchar(50), mail varchar(50));
 insert into users values (1  , 'toto' , 'tata'     , 'toto.tata@gmail.com');
 insert into users values (2  , 'titi' , 'tutu'     , 'titi.tutu@gmail.com');
```

Update query:

```
 update users set username=(select username from users where id=2) where id=1;
 delete from users where id=2;
```

Select query:

```
 select * from users
```

| id | name | username | mail |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | toto | tutu | toto.tata@gmail.com |

*db<fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=77ac14fc8c756f973fd66e55c8edc2fa)*

Answer (score 0):

You could use aggregation:

```
select min(id) as id,
       max(name) filter (where id = 1) as name,
       max(username) filter (where id = 2) as username,
       max(mail) filter (where id = 1) as mail
from t
where id in (1, 2);
```

This assumes that you want to pull particular column values from particular `id`s.

Or you could use `join`:

```
select t1.id, t1.name, t2.username, t1.mail
from t t1 join
     t t2
     on t1.id = 1 and t2.id = 2;
```

If you actually want to *change* the data, use `update` and `delete`:

```
update t t1
    set username = t2.username
    from t t2
    where t1.id = 1 and t2.id = 2;

delete from t
    where t.id = 2;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=65f9c70a297487a00cfcacbfb7d09eb0) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: I tried your solution but I have an issues. I want that t and t1 (in your update) is the same table ? How can I do that ? Because after I tried your thing this is what I get : ```ERREUR:  le nom de la table « WU_Users » est spécifié plus d'une fois
CONTEXTE : instruction SQL « UPDATE "WU_Users" "WU_Users"
            SET "username" = "WU_Users.username"
            from "WU_Users" "WU_Users"
            WHERE "WU_Users"."id" = 1 and "WU_Users"."id" = 2 »
fonction PL/pgsql inline_code_block, ligne 7 à instruction SQL```

Comment: @MathieuArthur . . . I added a db<>fiddle (and fixed a typo not related to the code in your comment).  The code works fine.  The code in your comment is missing an alias in the `from` clause.